# Как правильно использовать класс в другом классе?

Tags: java, android

Создаю класс:

```
public class CardData {
  public long ID = 19740408181830L;
  public static String Name = "Alex";
  public static String Date = "08.04.1974";
  public static int year = 1974;
  public static int month = 4;
  public static int day = 8;
  public static Double[] AllRes1 = new Double[32];
  public static Double[] AllRes2 = new Double[13];
  public CardData() {
  }
}
```

Создаю класс для расчетов:

```
public class CalcAll {
   public void getAllRes(){

    }
}
```

В основном Активити создаю экземпляр

```
CardData carddate;
  carddate.ID= 01244343432;
  carddate.Name= "Alex";
  carddate.year= "2000";
```

Как мне передать в класс CalcAll поля созданного экземпляра, произвести с ними операции и сохранить в полях экземпляра AllRes1[] посчитанные данные, чтобы использовать их также не только в основном Активити, но и в других.
Т.е. как правильно это все делается?

Comment: Да, основ ООП явно не хватает.

Comment: Если данные требуются в нескольких активити лучше всего использовать внешнее хранилище, например БД, тем более, что при вашем подходе введенные данные все равно будут утрачены при выходе из приложения, то есть такое решение не имеет практического смысла.

Comment: Мне не нужно их хранить после выхода. Вернее, то что нужно и так хранится с помощью SQLite. Мне нужно понять как это сделать. Я уверен это легко, только что-то никто не хочет заморачиваться делать пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

```
public class CalcAll {
    private CardData cardData;  // Создаём объект типа CardData.

    public void setCardData(CardData card) {
        this.cardData = card;   //При вызове метода, объекту CardData будет присвоена ссылка на card.
    }

    public CardData getCardData() {
        return cardData;
    }
}
```

В активити сделать так.

```
CardData carddate = new CardData();
        carddate.ID = 123123;              // Лучше в классе CardData
        carddate.Name = "Alex";            // поменяйте доступ с public на private
        carddate.year = 2000;              // и под нужные поля создайте set get методы.

        CalcAll calc = new CalcAll();
        calc.setCardData(carddate);   // Передаём методу наш объект.
```

И для того, чтобы обратится с static полям не нужно создавать для этого объект.
Нужно указать название_класса.поле

Comment: Супер!!! Это то, что мне надо. Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 0):

Более правильным решением будет, в создании экземпляра в переопределенном классе Application, чтобы объект класса не был пересоздан при пересоздании Активности, для получение объекта из других классов создать геттер в Application, и общаться к нему.

Так же к пользователям Yura Ivanov и Eugene Krivenja, стоит прислушаться

Comment: Да я согласен, что не хватает базовых знаний. Просто как всегда нужно быстро что-то делать, а времени разбираться не хватает. Про геттер спасибо, поищу как это делается.